# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected - LDAP

Tags: php

I am trying to load the LDAP plugin for the http://www.question2answer.org/addons.php page.
LDAP plugin here: https://github.com/zakkak/qa-ldap-login/blob/master/README.md.

Following the directions from the Readme, I am getting the following errors:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\UniServer\www\qa-lab\qa-plugin\qa-ldap-login-master\ldap-login.php on line 30

Here is a copy of the ldap-login.php file.
Line 30 is:
$username = explode("@", $email)[0];

```
<?php

    class ldap_login {

      function load_module($directory, $urltoroot)
      {
        $this->directory=$directory;
        $this->urltoroot=$urltoroot;
      } // end function load_module

      // check_login checks to see if user is already logged in by looking for
      // a cookie or session variable (dependent on 'remember me' setting
      function check_login()
      {
        if(!isset($_COOKIE["qa-login_fname"]) && !isset($_SESSION["qa-login_fname"])) {
          return false;
        } else {
          if(isset($_COOKIE["bdops-login_fname"])){
            $fname = $_COOKIE["qa-login_fname"];
            $lname = $_COOKIE["qa-login_lname"];
            $email = $_COOKIE["qa-login_email"];
          } else {
            $fname = $_SESSION["qa-login_fname"];
            $lname = $_SESSION["qa-login_lname"];
            $email = $_SESSION["qa-login_email"];
          }
          $source = 'ldap';
          $identifier = $email;

          $username = explode("@", $email)[0];
          $fields['email'] = $email;
          $fields['confirmed'] = true;
          $fields['handle'] = $username;
          $fields['name'] = $fname . " " . $lname;
          qa_log_in_external_user($source,$identifier,$fields);
        }
      } // end function check_login

      function match_source($source)
      {
        return $source=='ldap';
      } // end function match_source

      function login_html($tourl, $context)
      {

      } // end function login_html

      function logout_html ($tourl)
      {
        require_once QA_INCLUDE_DIR."qa-base.php";

        $_SESSION['logout_url'] = $tourl;
        $logout_url = qa_path('auth/logout', null, qa_path_to_root());
        echo('<a href="'.$logout_url.'">'.qa_lang_html('main/nav_logout').'</a>');
      } // end function logout_html

    } // end class ldap_login

    ?>
```

I should also include, the ldap info I used:

```
        <?php

    $ldap_search_strings = array( 'uid=myusername,ou=users,ou=hq,dc=domain.net,dc=com');
    $ldap_hostname = 'ldap://ldap.domain.net'; // use ldap:// for non ssl encrypted servers
    $ldap_port = 389; // use 389 for non ssl encrypted servers

    ?>
```

Comment: Are you running PHP 5.4? If not, that syntax is invalid. Array dereferencing is available in 5.4+ but not before - you need to store the output of `explode()` in a variable.

Comment: Or use something like `list($username,) = explode("@", $email);` to discard the other part and store the username directly into `$username`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$username = explode("@", $email)[0];
```

This syntax isn't available in PHP versions prior to 5.4

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php
>
> Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0]

You'd have to change it to something like this:

```
$segments = explode("@", $email);
$username = $segments[0];
```

Or in this case since it's grabbing the first array item, perhaps use:

```
$username = current(explode("@", $email));
```

Comment: Have a new error now:
Getting this error now:

Warning: require_once(C:/UniServer/www/qa-lab/qa-include/../qa-plugin/qa-ldap-login/qa-ldap-process.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\UniServer\www\qa-lab\qa-include\qa-page-login.php on line 61 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/UniServer/www/qa-lab/qa-include/../qa-plugin/qa-ldap-login/qa-ldap-process.php' (include_path='.;C:/UniServer/home/us_pear/PEAR') in C:\UniServer\www\qa-lab\qa-include\qa-page-login.php on line 61

Comment: I think this problem is here, but I am not sure what to change it to:

require_once QA_INCLUDE_DIR.'../qa-plugin/qa-ldap-login/qa-ldap-process.php';

Comment: Thanks Wesley.  I now face a new issue.  The site won't throw any errors, other than "user not found".  I have the full set of files for this ldap plugin.  I can't seem to get it working.